# Magento 2 Migration Tool - Verify if Migration is successful from 1.9 - 2.0 CE

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

`mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc`

[image: etc]

`mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce`

[image: ce-to-ce]

`mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.2.2`

[image: 1.9.2.2]

`mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.2.2\config.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <source version="1.9.2.2">
        <database host="localhost" name="magento9" user="root"/>
    </source>
    <destination version="2.0.2">
        <database host="localhost" name="mage2" user="root"/>
    </destination>
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <options>
        <crypt>
            <key>1bc968bd50b96ee18388feaed3bc1f1d</key>
        </crypt>

        <map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/map.xml</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/map-eav.xml</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <class_map>etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/class-map.xml</class_map>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix />
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    </options>
</config>
```

`settings.xml` is copied from path `mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce`

Added settings.xml.dist and map.xml.dist at location mage2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc

In CMD prompt I am executing below commands for `settings` and `data` migration respectively

`php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml`

`php bin/magento migrate:data vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.2/config.xml`

and it says `Migration Compelted`.

After flushing cache and reindexing, I do not see any changes in my Mage 2.0 installation. Its the same.

To use the mapping files:

```
1. Rename or copy them to remove the .dist extension.
2. Edit them using the schema located in <your Magento 2 install   dir>/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc.
3. Then change config.xml in <options> node with the new name of the file.
```

1. How can I verify if settings and data are migrated successfully ?
2. Have I made any mistake in Configuring the migration OR
   Configuration and mapping files ?

Reference URL - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html

Comment: you have to check for database table core_config_data and admin panel stores -> configuration are import from magento 1.

Comment: @rakesh nothing is imported. I changed base currency and default country and also created new customer group in 1.9. Nothing is reflected in 2.0. Which columns to check in code_config_data table to ensure it works ?

Comment: you have successfully done migrate setting. in setting mode, only affcted configuration page of magento 2

Comment: If its successfully done, why I do not see any changes in 2.0? Also I have migrated data apart from settings but its not seen anywhere..

Comment: have you set proper your old db and new db name in config.xml  inside source and destination tag, Also you can check log file.

Comment: Okay, I am able to import settings now. Updating my config.xml file. But trying to migrate data throws exception - Integrity check failed

Comment: please set <source_prefix /> if old db have, if old db with table start with mt_ then you have keep <source_prefix >mt_</source_prefix >

Comment: I don't have any source_prefix or destination_prefix. It's table name only with out any prefixes

Comment: have you checked your log file for migration?

Comment: One of the exception `[ERROR]: Source fields are missing or not mapped. Document: customer_eav_attribute. Fields: is_used_for_customer_segment` How do I troubleshoot mapping source fields ? Also are you referring var/log file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below solutions, with file name,

```
magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.2.1/map.xml
```

you have to keep below tag inside `<source><document_rules>`

```
<ignore>   
      <field>customer_eav_attribute.is_used_for_customer_segment</field>
</ignore>
```

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on the accepted answer with some additions.

For every custom attribute or table you get an integrity check error like yours, you need to (or can) define an ignore rule.

They are defined for `<source>` and `<destination>` on `<document_rules>` and `<field_rules>`.

Besides ignore you can use *rename* rules for documents or transforms on attributes to create an adapter for your migration. 
This way you can make a meaningful transform if you really need it.

The xml already provides the foundation for this extract - transform - load (etl).

They describe it more thoroughly here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html#migration-config

The below xml shows all possible configurations:

```
<map xmlns:xs="." xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="map.xsd">
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>some_document2</document>
        </ignore>
        <rename>
            <document>some_document</document>
            <to>some_dest_document</to>
        </rename>
        <log_changes>
            <document key="primary_key">some_dest_document</document>
        </log_changes>
    </document_rules>

    <field_rules>
        <move>
            <field>some_document1.field1</field>
            <to>some_document1.field2</to>
        </move>
        <ignore>
            <field>some_document3.field8</field>
        </ignore>
        <transform>
            <field>some_document1.field1</field>
            <handler class="\Migration\Handler\Convert">
                <param name="map" value="[value1:value2;value3:value4;value5:value6;]" />
            </handler>
        </transform>
    </field_rules>
</source>
<destination>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>some_document8</document>
        </ignore>
    </document_rules>

    <field_rules>
        <transform>
            <field>some_document5.field3</field>
            <handler class="\Migration\Handler\SetValue">
                <param name="value" value="10" />
            </handler>
        </transform>
    </field_rules>
</destination>
</map>
```