# Magento 1.9 to 2.0.2 migration issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

After installing magento2 followed [these steps](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html) to configure migration tool and then tried to migrate data using [this link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html). At the end tried to execute the following command

Run the settings migration command:

```
bin/magento migrate:settings [-r|--reset] {<path to config.xml>}
```

in my case it is:

```
php mage22\bin\magento migrate:data [-r|--reset] E:\wamp\www\mage22\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml
```

I got this error in commamd prompt `'--reset]' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

What was wrong and How to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset (`-r` OR `--reset`) is used to migrate from begining OR from start. If you are doing migration first time, just remove `-r` OR `--reset`. Also `-r` and `--reset` are alternate arguments, you can use **ONLY** one at a time (**both works SAME**).

Run this command :

```
php mage22\bin\magento migrate:data E:\wamp\www\mage22\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml
```

If you are trying more that once, try this:

```
php mage22\bin\magento migrate:data -r E:\wamp\www\mage22\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml
```

**OR** (works same as above)

```
php mage22\bin\magento migrate:data --reset E:\wamp\www\mage22\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried with the commands. I got this error:
`[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000][1049] Base 'mage19' inconnue
[PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000][1049] Base 'mage19' inconnue
migrate:data [-r|--reset] config
`

Comment: FYI: mage19 is my magento 1.9 version.

Comment: go to `mage22` directory (`cd mage22`) and try : `php bin\magento migrate:data -r E:\wamp\www\mage22\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml`

Comment: Now Results this error: `[Migration\Exception] Invalid config filename: E:\wamp\www\mage22\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\config.xml
` when changed config.xml.dist. When removed `.dist` from extension it results the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception` and `PDOException`

Comment: As per error, make sure, you config `config.xml` correctly. Check here : http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool-configure.html , Also check if `config.xml` exist at that location ?

Comment: Yes it is there. But it shows again `[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception] SQLSTATE[HY000][1049] Base 'mage19' inconnue [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000][1049] Base 'mage19' inconnue migrate:data [-r|--reset] config `

Comment: I have checked this link too http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101369/magento-2-migration-tool-verify-if-migration-is-successful-from-1-9-2-0-ce

Comment: Thank you @Anil. It is worked. Error was because incorrect db name in config.xml.

Comment: Glad that helps :-)